# How to connect multiple tables to a single model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have quite a complex model which has many attached columns - around 40, and so I have split them up into multiple tables:

```
business
business_details
```

I was hoping I won't have to create a BusinessDetails model and use relationship Business has_one BusinessDetails.

How do I connect business to business_details and access both through the model Business?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
class BusinessDetails < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :business
end

class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :business_details

  delegate :bd_field1, :bd_field2, :to => :business_details, :allow_nil => true
end
```

Comment: Well, maybe not a good solution.  The behavior and object state are even more important to break out than the database tables.  Yet, this is what the asker was looking for, and it's a good incremental step to organizing the data.